# How can I configure vite in my vue app to serve cesiiumjs directories as static files?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, cesiumjs

I have a sample app at [my-vue-app](https://github.com/eric-g-97477-vue/my-vue-app) which demonstrates the problem.

The app builds and starts to run, but I get a lot of errors like:

```
Resource.js:2256     GET http://localhost:5173/Assets/approximateTerrainHeights.json 404 (Not Found)
bingAerial.png:1     GET http://localhost:5173/Widgets/Images/ImageryProviders/bingAerial.png 404 (Not Found)
TouchRotate.svg:1    GET http://localhost:5173/Widgets/Images/NavigationHelp/TouchRotate.svg 404 (Not Found)
Resource.js:2256     GET http://localhost:5173/Assets/Textures/SkyBox/tycho2t3_80_mx.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

The "Configuring CESIUM_BASE_URL" section at [CesiumJS Quickstart](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs-learn/cesiumjs-quickstart/) says:

> Configure your module bundler to copy the following four directories and serve them as static files

Based on this information, I added to [main.js](https://github.com/eric-g-97477-vue/my-vue-app/blob/main/src/main.js):

```
window.CESIUM_BASE_URL = '';
```

and changed [vite.config.js](https://github.com/eric-g-97477-vue/my-vue-app/blob/main/vite.config.js) to:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { join } from 'path';
import serveStatic from 'serve-static';
import path from 'path';

import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue()
  ],

  server: {
    middleware: [
      serveStatic(join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'cesium', 'Build', 'Cesium'))
    ]
  }
})
```

Unfortunately, the behavior did not change.

I am not sure what more I need to do to make this work.

Does anyone have any advice?